# Using Oversim SimpleUnderlay network with different Churn generator types

Tags: configuration, simulation, omnet++, churn

I'm using `SimpleUnderlay.ned` network in `Oversim20121206` and `OMNet++ ver 4.6` to implement a hierarchical overlay network (2 layers). In the configuration (.ini) file I used the following (sample):

```
    **.churnGeneratorTypes = "oversim.common.NoChurn oversim.common.LifetimeChurn”
    **.terminalTypes = "oversim.underlay.simpleunderlay.SimpleMultiOverlayHost \
oversim.underlay.simpleunderlay.SimpleOverlayHost”.
```

When trying to assign some parameters in the `*.ini` file, I get the following errors

[image: screenshot from Omnet IDE showing the <code>"*.ini"</code> file and the error messages]

The error is "`unknown per-object configuration.[parameter name].

Is there any recommendation for configuration files that need to assign parameters to nodes with different churn profiles? Any proposals?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you marked `inet` as reference project in your project? Are you able to successfully build your project?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The answer is Yes 'inet' is a reference in the project. I am able to build the project, however the above errors appear in the '.ini' file. If you have any example of a similar file using 'simpleunderlay.ned' and 'underlayconfiguratior.ned', will be of great help. Thanks

Comment: Actually, these "errors" in an ini file are not _real_ errors. They mean only that IDE does not understand these parameters. It is very common in `OMNeT++`, especially when type of a module in not hard-coded in NED, but it is defined in ini file.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately, the simulator is not able to run the simulation. The simulation run terminates with 'exit code:1' prior to any display of the network configuration in the IDE.

Comment: Have you checked both `inet` and `Oversim` as reference projects? Set in your ini: `debug-on-errors=true`, build the project in debug mode and debug it. The execution will stop just before the line that causes an error.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for your help. Your hints were quite helpful. The problem was solved long ago.